# How to use dvorak-intl without deadkeys

Tags: dvorak

I have found `dvorak-alt-intl` but is not what I need because is not good to write Spanish with a US layout. 
I use Sway manager I couldn't make work `nodeadkeys` in xkb_variant.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What Unix are you using?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I use Archlinux. The question is "[how to use] dvorak-intl without deadkeys". I have found the solution here [link](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config/-/issues/2)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution here https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config/-/issues/2

I put the layout definition in `~/.xkb/symbosl/dvorak-intl-ndk` and loaded in the input section of Sway .config like this:

```
xkb_layout dvorak-intl-ndk
```

layout definition:

```
// Dvorak international with no dead keys
// Based on Dvorak intl. above
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "dvorak-intl-ndk" {

    include "us(dvorak)"
    name[Group1]= "English (Dvorak, intl., no dead keys)";

    key <TLDE> { [     grave,   asciitilde,  dead_grave,          dead_tilde] };

    key <AE01> { [         1,       exclam,    exclamdown,       onesuperior] };
    key <AE02> { [         2,           at,   twosuperior,  dead_doubleacute] };
    key <AE03> { [         3,   numbersign, threesuperior,       dead_macron] };
    key <AE04> { [         4,       dollar,      currency,          sterling] };
    key <AE05> { [         5,      percent,      EuroSign,      dead_cedilla] };
    key <AE06> { [         6,  asciicircum,    onequarter,   dead_circumflex] };
    key <AE07> { [         7,    ampersand,       onehalf                   ] };
    key <AE08> { [         8,     asterisk, threequarters,      dead_ogonek ] };
    key <AE09> { [         9,    parenleft, leftsinglequotemark, dead_breve ] };
    key <AE10> { [         0,   parenright, rightsinglequotemark, dead_abovering ] };
    key <AE11> { [ bracketleft,  braceleft,  guillemotleft, leftdoublequotemark ] };
    key <AE12> { [bracketright, braceright, guillemotright, rightdoublequotemark ] };

    key <AD01> { [apostrophe,   quotedbl,      dead_acute,    dead_diaeresis] };
    key <AD02> { [     comma,       less,       ccedilla,          Ccedilla] };
    key <AD03> { [    period,    greater,   dead_abovedot,        dead_caron] };
    key <AD04> { [         p,          P,      odiaeresis,        Odiaeresis] };
    key <AD05> { [         y,          Y,      udiaeresis,        Udiaeresis] };
 // key <AD06> { [         f,          F                                    ] };
 // key <AD07> { [         g,          G                                    ] };
    key <AD08> { [         c,          C,       copyright,              cent] };
    key <AD09> { [         r,          R,      registered,        registered] };
    key <AD10> { [         l,          L,          oslash,          Ooblique] };
    key <AD11> { [     slash,   question,    questiondown                   ] };
 // key <AD12> { [     equal,       plus,        multiply,          division] };
    key <AC01> { [         a,          A,          aacute,            Aacute] };
    key <AC02> { [         o,          O,          oacute,            Oacute] };
    key <AC03> { [         e,          E,          eacute,            Eacute] };
    key <AC04> { [         u,          U,          uacute,            Uacute] };
    key <AC05> { [         i,          I,          iacute,            Iacute] };
    key <AC06> { [         d,          D,             eth,               ETH] };
 // key <AC07> { [         h,          H                                    ] };
    key <AC08> { [         t,          T,           thorn,             THORN] };
    key <AC09> { [         n,          N,          ntilde,            Ntilde] };
    key <AC10> { [         s,          S,          ssharp,           section] };
 // key <AC11> { [     minus, underscore,             yen,     dead_belowdot] };

    key <AB01> { [ semicolon,      colon,       paragraph,           degree ] };
    key <AB02> { [         q,          Q,      adiaeresis,       Adiaeresis ] };
 // key <AB03> { [         j,          J                                    ] };
    key <AB04> { [         k,          K,              oe,                OE] };
 // key <AB05> { [         x,          X                                    ] };
 // key <AB06> { [         b,          B                                    ] };
    key <AB07> { [         m,          M,              mu,                mu] };
    key <AB08> { [         w,          W,           aring,             Aring] };
 // key <AB09> { [         v,          V                                    ] };
    key <AB10> { [         z,          Z,              ae,                AE] };

    key <BKSL> { [ backslash,        bar,       notsign,        brokenbar ] };

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```